# Ionic ng-hide/ng-show scroll issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently building an Ionic app for someone but I'm having some issues with ng-hide and ng-scroll. The page shows a product and you can switch between seeing the nutrients or the ingredients. I use ng-hide & ng-show to achieve this. However, when I press the button to switch data, the scrollbar messes up. I attached a short video to demonstrate the issue: 
https://youtu.be/W9fFMdSLW8s

Here are some code snippets that may be useful to gain insight.

### Codepen

EDIT: I made a codepen that reproduces the issue:

http://codepen.io/JeremyKeusters/pen/qmBwzp

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Please make sure that the browser height and the preview window is not too big.
2. Click on the green 'show nutrients' button and **try to scroll down immediately**. (use mouse & drag to scroll as if you were using a phone)
3. You will notice that you're blocked and can't scroll down. The solution is to wait a couple of seconds until the scroll 'resets'.
4. Try to click the green button on the bottom again. You'll see that there's a lot of white space in which you can scroll (the scroll area is too big). The solution is again to wait a couple of seconds until it resets.

### Code

**template page:**

```
  <table class="ingredients" ng-show="toggle">
    <tr>
      <th class="left">Ingredient</th>
      <th class="right">Amount per<br>100 ml</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="ingredient in JuiceIngredients">
      <td class="left">{{ingredient.Ingredient.Name}}</td>
      <td class="right">{{ingredient.Ingredient.Amount_g}} g</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="nutrients" ng-hide="toggle">
    <tr>
      <th class="left">Nutrient</th>
      <th class="right">Amount per 100 ml</th>
      <th class="right">% of reference quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="nutrient in JuiceNutrients">
      <td class="left">{{nutrient.Nutrient.Name}}</td>
      <td class="right" ng-bind-html="nutrient.Nutrient.Amount_html"></td>
      <td class="right">{{(nutrient.Nutrient.PartOfRI * 100 | number:0)}} %</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="toggle=!toggle;" class="button button-block button-balanced default-button">
    <span ng-hide="toggle">Show ingredients</span>
    <span ng-show="toggle">Show nutrients</span>
  </button>
```

**controller.js:**

```
  bottleSrv.getBottleDetails($rootScope.scannedCode).then(function (data) {
    $scope.JuiceID = data.JuiceID;
    $scope.ExpirationDate = data.ExpirationDate;
    $scope.JuiceImg = "https://someurl.com/task.php?token=" + $rootScope.userToken + "&juice_id=" + data.JuiceID + "";

    juiceSrv.getJuiceDetails($scope.JuiceID).then(function (data) {
      $scope.JuiceName = data.Name;
      $scope.JuiceDescription = data.Description;
    })

    juiceSrv.getJuiceIngredients($scope.JuiceID).then(function (data) {
      $scope.JuiceIngredients = data;
    })

    juiceSrv.getJuiceNutrients($scope.JuiceID).then(function (data) {
      $scope.JuiceNutrients = data;
    })
  });
```

Does someone has a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance for helping out!

-Jérémy

Comment: When you click on button then they display other page of some x item right and then scroll comes up with bottom that is issue?

Comment: Not really.. When I click on the button, it shows other content via ng-hide and ng-show (and via the 'toggle' variable). When I click and the new content is for example shorter than the old one, the scrolling doesn't adapt and you're able to scroll too far down. Also, when the new content is longer than the old one, you can't see the entire new content as the 'max scroll' is too short..

Comment: Can you put working code in plunkr?

Comment: Just check that is happen in iOS only or in android too? because i check in android that is working fine.

Comment: @PareshGami I'll check, but you can see that in CodePen it doesn't work either, and CodePen is nor iOS nor Android..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer for this issue. I added the overflow-scroll element to the ion-content element.

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
```

This resolved the issue. It does messes up a bit with the bottom spacing, but you can fix that with some CSS.

Answer (score 1):

We you click button call one function in controller and resize height of document using `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize();`

### html

```
<button ng-hide="toggle" ng-click="toggleButton()" class="button button-block button-balanced default-button">
Show ingredients
</button>

<button ng-show="toggle" ng-click="toggleButton()" class="button button-block button-balanced default-button">
Show nutrients
</button>
```

### js

```
$scope.toggle = false;
$scope.toggleButton = function() 
{
  $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
  $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
};
```

### Note

Add dependency in controller called `$ionicScrollDelegate`

Comment: Thanks @Paresh Gami for the answer, but made the issue even worse! There's even more spacing now..

Comment: @NickyTheWrench Glad